# Load and display an image from URL that not ending with "png" or "jpeg"

Tags: r, image

I want to load and display an image from URL to R. The url linkage is not ending with ".jpeg" or ".png". For example, https://placekitten.com/200/300

Any easy way to do that? Thanks.

The below is the R script I use to load the url with ".jpg" as the ending

```
library(imager)
im <- load.image("https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg")
plot(im)
```

Comment: Just load into R, and display in R. For the images with ".jpeg" or ".png" at the end, I can use the R function "load.image" in the package "imager” to load, and use the R function "plot" to display

Comment: Added the R script now. But it could not solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do it using the R package "magick"

```
myurl <- "http://placekitten.com/500/300"

library(magick)

pic <- image_read(myurl)

plot(pic)
```